# FreeBSD optional components deinstall

Tags: freebsd

How deinstall optional components **world/games**, **world/doc** etc.?

Comment: The question is quite clear - FreeBSD has a set of optional components that can be installed during installation.  The OP is simply asking how to remove them post-install. Why does this have a close vote for being *unclear what you're asking*?

Answer (score 1):

You can't deinstall them. But if you build FreeBSD from source you can configure what components do you want (see [FreeBSD documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/makeworld.html), [man make.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make.conf&sektion=5&n=1) and [man src.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=src.conf&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)).

With [freebsd-update](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?freebsd-update%288%29) you can select which components do you want update (see [man freebsd-update.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?freebsd-update.conf%285%29)):

> **Components**
>                     The parameters following this keyword are the
>                   components or sub-components of FreeBSD which
>                   will be updated.  The components are `src`
>                   (source code), `world` (non-kernel binaries),
>                   and `kernel`; the sub-components are the indi-
>                   vidual distribution sets generated as part of
>                   the release process (e.g., `src/base`,
>                   `src/sys`, `world/base`, `world/catpages`,
>                   `kernel/smp`).    Note that prior to
>                   FreeBSD 6.1, the `kernel` component was dis-
>                   tributed as part of `world/base`.
>
> ```
>             This option can be specified multiple times, and
>             the parameters accumulate.
> ```

Comment: "But if you build it..." What does "it" refer to? The "deinstall" in your first sentence? The FreeBSD the OP is referring to? Build optional components the OP is asking about?

Comment: It's only a possibility. Yes, I know it isn't "deinstall" but the result is exactly what he want.

I wasn't exactly, I will edit my answer. Thanks!